# how to make webseal and IHS together as reverse proxy sever

Tags: httpserver, webseal

we are aware that we wont get support from IBM for clm applications with Webseal as reverse proxy. But we have to deploy our clm applications on an environment where webseal is already using as a reverse proxy.

So we came into a decision that, we will configure clm applications with IHS as reverse proxy and then will  make this to run behind webseal.

So our architecture plan is like

Webseal --> IHS ---> CLM appications with Liberty.

We can configure the applications with IHS reverse proxy. But we are not sure that how to make this setup behind a webseal and where we need your help

Comment: Any advise here